# Fade out spinner right before data are binded to scope in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase

The following code will fade out the spinner after it actually bind data from Firebase.

```
myFactory.$bindTo($scope, 'fact').then(function() {
  $('#spinner').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

But how can I fade it out half a second **before** the data gets binded?

Comment: Since you can hardly predict the amount of time the request will last, I am afraid its not possible. Maybe you can do some statistical measurements and figure out a way to forecast the amount of time the request will last :)

Comment: So it isn't possible today? Maybe in the future? ;) Oh no, must be some way to do this... I really want such a behavior:)

Comment: i'm not familiar with `firebase` , how ever you can check whether you can delay the binding by half a second, what you trying to do it difficult or not possible as i know.

Comment: Ohhhh yee, this is something;)) Gonna check it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which would delay the binding by half a second once the data is loaded.

```
myFactory.$loaded().then(function() {
  $('#spinner').fadeOut(1000);
  $timeout(function() {
    myFactory.$bindTo($scope, 'fact');
  }, 500);
});
```